# Populate Laravel form with Auth::user

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5

I've used a form to save my user's requests in a database.
Requests can be made without logging in, but also while logged in.

When someone is logged in, their info should be put into the form already, so they won't have to.

I wrote this in one of my form parts, to retreive their info, but it returns code:

```
<?php echo e(Auth::user()->organisation); ?>
```

The form is put like this:

```
{!! Form::Text('organisation', '{{{ Auth::user()->organisation }}}', array('required' => 'required')) !!}
```

I know it's probably something really small that i'm missing, but I can't put my finger on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code should look like this:

```
{!! Form::text('organisation', Auth::user()->organisation, ['required' => true]) !!}
```

Sometimes you want to check if organization in not empty:

```
{!! Form::text('organisation', empty(Auth::user()->organisation) ? '' : Auth::user()->organisation, ['required' => true]) !!}
```

Comment: Ah, so I used the wrong brackets for the required and that screwed up the rest?

Comment: Using `{{{ }}}` brackets is wrong. `array()` and `'required' => 'required'` or even `'required' => 'hey!'` will work, but it's less readable in my opinion.

Comment: Well thanks for explaining it so clearly. You're one of the good people on here